# Unexpected behavior of ImplicitRegion -> RegionPlot

Tags: bugs, regions, implicit

I have two semicircles that are identical except that the second is shifted one unit to the right.

```
R1 := ImplicitRegion[0 <= y <= Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, y}]
R2 := ImplicitRegion[0 <= y <= Sqrt[1 - (x - 1)^2], {x, y}]
```

When I plot them I get

[image: Expected behavior of RegionPlot]
[image: Unexpected behavior of RegionPlot]

What's up with the second plot? It should look the same as the first, right? Is this somehow a result of imaginary values of `Sqrt`?

Comment: I've reproduced this and passed it along to the developers.

Comment: @rcollyer Awesome, thanks! Some more (related) unexpected behavior is described in my comments on the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow *Mathematica* allows your variables to be Imaginary.  Restrict them to Reals, and all works fine:

```
R1 := Assuming[{x, y} \[Element] Reals, 
   ImplicitRegion[0 <= y <= Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, y}]];
R2 := Assuming[{x, y} \[Element] Reals, 
   ImplicitRegion[0 <= y <= Re@Sqrt[1 - (x - 1)^2], {x, y}]];
```

Hmmm.... it is curious that one must specify the full range of $x$ in `RegionPlot[R2]`, but if you recast the equations this way:

```
R3 := Assuming[{x, y} \[Element] Reals, 
   ImplicitRegion[(x - 1)^2 +  y^2 <= 1 && y > 0, {x, y}]];
```

all works fine.

Comment: This looks great. (I used `RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[{x, y} \[Element] Reals && 0 <= y <= Sqrt[1 - (x - 1)^2], {x, y}]]`, which gives the same result as your `R2`.) However, I only get a quarter-circle unless I also specify `0 ≤ x ≤ 2`. Is there any way to have Mathematica figure out the window automatically?

Comment: Hm. Very odd... I notice that I can drop the `Real` checking entirely with your amendment: `RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[(x - 1)^2 + y^2 <= 1 && y >= 0, {x, y}]]`. I think your solution is the most foolproof. If there's documentation on the possible inaccuracies of `RegionPlot` I'd love to see it, but the current docs don't even mention the `RegionPlot[region]` syntax yet.

Comment: @raxod502 - The form `RegionPlot[region]` is indirectly documented by the documentation for [ImplicitRegion](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html).

Answer (score 6):

Since you shifted the oval you must shift the domain of `x` for the second region

```
R1 := ImplicitRegion[-1 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, y}]

R2 := ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 2 && 0 <= y <= Sqrt[1 - (x - 1)^2], {x, y}]

GraphicsRow[RegionPlot /@ {R1, R2}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why I have to specify the domain at all (for instance, I didn't have to in `R1`). For an `ImplicitRegion`, shouldn't Mathematica be able to figure it out automatically?

Comment: @raxod502 -  I agree that Mathematica should be able to figure it out; however, when you experience a problem then add information that you know: `FunctionDomain[Sqrt[1 - x^2], x]` is `-1 <= x <= 1` and `FunctionDomain[Sqrt[1 - (x - 1)^2], x]` is `0 <= x <= 2`.