# ImplicitRegion RegionPlot fails for circle in 10.4.1

Tags: plotting, computational-geometry

This must have worked at some point, because the documentation for `ImplicitRegion` has the right picture. But when I evaluate

```
R = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[R]
```

I get an empty plot in 10.4.1.

It is not related to this generating a 1-d set. The following for example works fine:

```
R = ImplicitRegion[x == y, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[R]
```

Restricting the variables to be reals (as suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98079/6804)) does not change anything.

```
R = Assuming[{x, y} \[Element] Reals, 
   ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}]];
RegionPlot[R]
```

Is this a recently introduced bug?

Comment: it does work fine in 10.1.  Perhaps try setting `PlotPoints`

Comment: How very odd. `ImplicitRegion[x^2 - y^2 == 1, {x, y}] // RegionPlot` works, so that certainly is a mystery. It seems to hate ellipses in general; try `ImplicitRegion[2 x^2 + 3 y^2 == 1, {x, y}] // RegionPlot` as well.

Comment: The documentation says "RegionPlot will only visualize two-dimensional regions"  - use `ContourPlot` instead